# SC Red Clay New lawn

Tags: grass, sod, overseeding, fescue

We have a new house that fescue sod was put down in the front. We live in a clay area in SC and looking to finish the back yard and sides. What would be the best grass to use and when to seed. We are from NC where centipede was the king of grass and always grew in great soil. Red clay in SC is a new adventure for us. My husband does not like fescue grass and wants to change. What are your recommendations.